# Use numbered column references in Excel Conditional Formatting code in VBA script

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have some VBA script that applies some conditional formatting in Excel.

Is there a way that I can reference the number values of the columns instead of the normal cell reference.

This is what I currently have:

```
"=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(F3)),F3<>""SomeValue1"",F3<>""SomeValue1"")"
```

And this is the sort of thing I would like to achieve:

```
"=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(Cells(3,6))),Cells(3,6)<>""SomeValue1"",Cells(3,6)<>""SomeValue2"")"
```

Comment: `Cells(3,6)` is vba not formula and must be removed from the quotes and concatenated into the string,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Replace("=AND(NOT(ISBLANK({addr})),{addr}<>""SomeValue1"",{addr}<>""SomeValue2"")", _
        "{addr}", Cells(3,6).Address)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve my query using the following code to first convert the column number into a column letter:

```
ColLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColNumber).Address, "$")(1)
```

Once I had this conversion value I was able to use this variable in my code for conditional formatting:

```
"=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(" & ColLetter & "3))," & ColLetter & "3<>""SomeValue1""," & ColLetter & "3<>""SomeValue1"")"
```

Thanks to everyone whop responded.